# Wishart random variables

Tags: st.statistics, probability-distributions

I have a question about Wishart random variable. If X follows a Wishart distribution, then does X-Y follows a Wishart Distribution if Y is a Hermitian matrix?

Thanks.

Comment: that would be a socalled "noncentral Wishart distribution"

Answer (score 1):

Wishart distribution is a distribution on the set of non-negative definite matrices. Since X-Y can have negative eigenvalues I'll say no.